# Opencart 2 Change Search Button Color

Tags: css, opencart2.x

I know this question has been asked and answered but none of the solutions are working for me. I want to change the color of the search button in 2.0.3.1 and I have tried EVERYTHING. I cannot figure it out. I also want to change the hover color for the seach button and cart button from black and cannot do that either. This is driving me crazy. Can anyone help?

Answer (score 0):

modified btn-default on line 453. I am an idiot and just so exhausted. I hope this helps someone else.